# How to include a dependency to a jar file from an eclipse/osgi application?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, osgi

I created an Eclipse 4 application and I needed a `jar` offering a functionality as part of my application (this could be anything e.g. `log4j` to make it trivial).
I added the `jar` as part of my project's classpath (`Right Click->Configure Build Path`) but on runtime my service failed with a `ClassNotFound` error (from OSGI I guess?).
Anyway searching this it turned out, at least as I have understand it, that I should add the jar as part of another `Plugin` and create a dependency from my application/service to this new plugin.
I.e. I created a `Plugin Project from Existing JAR archives`.
This time the setup worked.
So if I understand this, when developing for Eclipse/OSGi we should not add `jars` in the classpaths directly but add them via plugins (why?).
**Question:** If I am correct so far, what is the standard practice to include `jars` when developing a project?
Define/Create one `Plugin Project from existing JAR archives` and add **all** the required third party libraries needed there, *or* have a different plugin project per needed `jar` *or* something else perhaps???
Sorry if my terminology is not accurate. I am new in OSGi and Eclipse programming

**Note:** When talking about `jars` I am not refering to other OSGi services. I am refering to the norm of using ready, reliable third party libraries that would be needed by many parts of an application. E.g. `log4j` or an xml parsing library or `apache commons` etc

Comment: What's your ultimate goal: Do you want to create a deliverable for "your" project, say a jar/zip which has all needed classes/jars/resources to run your program?

Comment: @thekashyap:Not sure I understand your question.The exported product is predefined by the `.product` configuration, right?So my concern is how the project should be setup so that in the deployment I know that all the required jars are available.

Comment: Check out: http://www.vogella.com/articles/OSGi/article.html and http://www.coderanch.com/t/104274/vc/Order-Export-tab-Java-Build

Comment: my bad.. didn't read "OSGi" anywhere in your question.. :-).. checkout the link I posted, it describes the "bundles" concept.. given teh OSGi architecture my guess would be that you should have all the basic services available as existing bundles.

Answer (score 5):

For the runtime it is always the Manifest and the headers there that control what is in your bundle classpath. There are three ways to get access to a jar:

1. Import-Package  header. This is the recommended way. You define one import per package you need. You jar you want to access has to be deployed in the runtime as a bundle. It also needs to export all needed packages.
2. Require-Bundle . This is another way to access bundles. You define the id of the bundle you need and see all packages it exports. As Require-Bundle binds you more closely to the other bundle the Import-Package way should be preferred.
3. Bundle-Classpath . This allows to add jars to your classpath that you embed into your own bundle. This should only be a last resort when the other way do not work. You can have nasty classloading issues when mixing this with the other methods.

You can find many pre built bundles in maven central. Many jars today already contain an OSGi manifest. For the cases where this is not true many jars are repackaged as bundles by servicemix. See groupId: org.apache.servicemix.bundles. There is also the spring bundle repository where you find some more.

Below I listed some resources you might want to read:

http://www.aqute.biz/Blog/2007-02-19

http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Import-Package

http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Require-Bundle

http://www.vogella.com/blog/2009/03/27/required-bundle-import-package/

Comment: For case (1) if I need to create a bundle for needed jars, should I put *all* the jars needed in this one bundle (in case I need more than one) **or** each jar should be in each own bundle?

Comment: I think the best way to make bundles from jars is to just add the Manifest entries. So each jar will be its own bundle. This has the advantage that your maven depdendency structure matches the bundles. Btw. if you have to create bundles take a look at bnd and the maven bundle plugin.

Answer (score 3):

The examples you have mentioned are available as OSGi bundles, so you don't need to make them bundles yourself.  You don't typically use direct jar dependencies in OSGi, you typically use package or bundle dependencies.  In the log4j example you are referring to, you should use **import package** as there can be multiple bundle providers (newer log4j jar, springsource bundled version of older log4j, slf4j implementation...).  This will disconnect your code dependencies from the actual provider.

These dependencies are maintained via you manifest, not your project classpath.  In an eclipse plugin project, the projects build classpath is derived from the entries in the manifest.

Even though you are not using services, all code dependencies are still maintained via the manifest.

Comment: But if I use the `import package` that means that the `jar` is somewhere in the `OSGi` container on deployment right?So how do I know which jars are already available?E.g. how would I know that `log4j` is already offered? And how would I use `apache commons`?Is that also already included?How is this possible?

Comment: Also I mean there are cases that I would need some jar not already offered as bundle, right?

Comment: Deployment of bundles for an application is implementation specific.  In eclipse, your target platform determines what bundles are available.  As for non bundled jars, you can simply create bundles for them with eclipse by creating a new plugin project form existing jar.  You could also include it within the bundle, but I prefer the bundle approach.

Comment: Yes this comes back to my original question.If I create a new plugin project from existing jar as you point out, should I include **all** my needed jars in that project **or** create a different bundle project for *each* jar needed?

Comment: I always go with the bundle per jar as it keeps things nicely componentized, which is what OSGi is all about.  It gets kind of ugly if one bundle is exporting unrelated packages, not to mention the fact that each of those jars will have it's own version, but the bundle will only have a single version.

Comment: `The examples you have mentioned are available as OSGi bundles`.I can not seem to find `org.apache.log4j` as part of Indigo's Imported Packages.Why is this?Do you mean something different here?

Comment: I opened a separate thread for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12660074/proper-way-to-include-log4j-in-an-eclipse-4-rcp-swt-osgi-application

Answer (score 3):

Extactaly  same problem we faced in our project. 
we have some legacy jar which are not OSGi compatible, we create lib folder parallel to BundleContent and added it into the classpath section of manifest.

```
Bundle-ClassPath: .,

 /lib/<legacy jar>.jar
```

There is no need to exporting and importing of packages unnecessarily if only one bundle is going to consume it,

Comment: +1 This bundle stuff is adding an unbearable overhead, especially when developing the JAR and the Eclipse plugin in parallel. Annoying, and at every iteration, it consumes time, kicks off you form the flow... I **vigorously hate Eclipse** for shunning Maven form the plugin development process. Yeah, there is Tycho, but I'd rather smack my own head with my freshly severed arm I just bit off my own shoulder until I feel comfortable than use that cryptic, undocumented band aid designed for the gaping septic wound that is Eclipse plugin legacy JAR dependency usage. Agile, NOT!